# Is there a way to fill missing dates and add an associated value of 0 in excel?

Tags: excel, date

I have some rainfall data in a timeseries which I am trying to plot in Excel. It looks like this:

[image]

In this format, the data misses the days on which no rain fell, i.e. the 2nd and 4th of February. This is important to show on the plot. Is there a way to fill these gaps in the time line and then fill the other column with 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=HSTACK(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)+1,1,MIN(A:A),1),BYROW(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)+1,1,MIN(A:A),1),LAMBDA(x,IFNA(VLOOKUP(x,A1:B5,2,FALSE),0))))
```

or

```
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)+1,1,MIN(A:A),1),HSTACK(a,BYROW(a,LAMBDA(x,IFNA(VLOOKUP(x,A1:B5,2,FALSE),0)))))
```

With idea from @David Leal for using `TAKE` to use in `MIN`, `MAX` so only one range as argument is needed:

```
=LET(a,A1:B5,b,TAKE(a,,1),c,SEQUENCE(MAX(b)-MIN(b)+1,1,MIN(b),1),HSTACK(c,BYROW(c,LAMBDA(x,IFNA(VLOOKUP(x,a,2,FALSE),0)))))
```

Result:

[image]

Or just simply drag date from your starting date down and use `VLOOKUP` formula also dragged down:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE),0)
```

Result:

[image]

(Date format used in examples is `yyyy/mm/dd`)

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following, put on cell `D1` the following formula (*formula 1*):

```
=LET(AB,A1:B5, A,TAKE(AB,,1), md,MIN(A), d,SEQUENCE(MAX(A)-md+1,,md),
 IFERROR(INDEX(AB,XMATCH(d,A),{1,2}),HSTACK(d,N(d<0))))
```

or using `XLOOKUP` as follows:

```
=LET(AB,A1:B5, A,TAKE(AB,,1), md,MIN(A), d,SEQUENCE(MAX(A)-md+1,,md),
 IFERROR(HSTACK(d,XLOOKUP(d,A,DROP(AB,,1))),HSTACK(d,N(d<0))))
```

### Update

As @VBasic2008 pointed out in the comment section, for `XLOOKUP` approach can be simplified using the 4th input argument as follows:

```
=LET(AB,A1:B5, A,TAKE(AB,,1), md,MIN(A), d,SEQUENCE(MAX(A)-md+1,,md),
 HSTACK(d,XLOOKUP(d,A,DROP(AB,,1),0)))
```

A comment about the performance of both options `XLOOKUP` and `INDEX/XMATCH`. Both functions can be optimized for large datasets forcing **binary search** since the dates (**lookup_array**) are sorted in ascending order, so we can set the input argument **search_mode** to `2` on both cases for `XMATCH` and `XLOOKUP` respectively. In terms of performance for `631K` rows using **search_mode** in both cases:

- `INDEX/XMATCH` version: `1.5secs` on average
- `XLOOKUP` version: `1sec` on average

which is expected since the first version has an additional function invocation: `IFERROR`. Not having a such additional call, both versions have the same performance, i.e. `INDEX/XMATCH` vs `XLOOKUP`.

For *formula 1*, it generates all expected dates (`d`), then identifies the rows from the input `AB` where the dates are found (if not returns  `{#N/A,#N/A}` on a given row). We use `IFERROR` to produce the output. We generate a constant array of zero values using the following trick `N(d<0)` because dates are always positive numbers in Excel

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Great! I don't understand the `HSTACK(d,N(d<0))` in the `XLOOKUP` version. Can't you just do `HSTACK(d,XLOOKUP(d,A,DROP(AB,,1),0))` without it and without the `IFERROR`?

Comment: Here's what I did: `=LET(Dates,A2:A21,Rain,B2:B21,m,MIN(Dates),s,SEQUENCE(MAX(Dates)-m+1,,m),HSTACK(s,XLOOKUP(s,Dates,Rain,0)))`. This way I'm allowing the columns not to be adjacent and spare myself of the `TAKE`, `DROP`, or `INDEX` business. It's hard to determine the inputs.

Comment: good catch @VBasic2008 I just adapted the previous approach to `XLOOKUP` without simplifying it as you did. Following your suggestion this would the formula: `=LET(AB,A1:B5, A,TAKE(AB,,1), md,MIN(A), d,SEQUENCE(MAX(A)-md+1,,md), HSTACK(d,XLOOKUP(d,A,DROP(AB,,1),0)))`. Let me know if you want me to update my question and credit to you, or if you prefer to post your approach. Thanks

Comment: That's why I posted the comment. Always feel free to update using any of my suggestions. You just forgot about the convenient 4th `XLOOKUP` argument.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks, I realized that the input data set (dates) are sorted in ascending order, so for a large dataset, it would be better in both cases `XMATCH` and `XLOOKUP` to use **search_mode** input argument and set it to `2`.